# How to redirect all paths to the same folder in apache?

Tags: apache

Seems like a really simple thing to do but i cant find anything to help me

how to redirect all requests to the same folder?

Ex:
"test.domain.com" is going correctly to "/opt/bitnami/projects/test/build"

What is the best way to keep "test.domain.com/page01" or "test.domain.com/page01/link2" going to folder "/opt/bitnami/projects/test/build" and not "/opt/bitnami/projects/test/build/page01"?

Do i need to create redirects?
That worked but creating infinite redirects

```
Redirect all requests to the main DocumentRoot
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1 [R,L]
```

Current virtualhost file below

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName test.domain.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/projects/test/build"
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/test.domain.com.br.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/test.domain.com.br.key"
  # BEGIN: Configuration for letsencrypt
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
  # END: Configuration for letsencrypt
  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location
  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
  </IfModule>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/projects/test/build">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
  <Location /.well-known>
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
      ProxyPass !
    </IfModule>
  </Location>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
</VirtualHost>
```